# Vim: Making Auto-Completion Smarter

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I use ctags, taglist, etc., to have auto completion in Vim. However, it is very limited compared to Visual Studio intellisense or Eclipse auto-completion. I am wondering whether it is possible to tune Vim to:

1. Show auto-completion whenever . or -> are typed. But only after some text that might be a variable (e.g. avoid showing auto completion after a number).
2. Show function parameters when ( is typed.
3. Stop removing the auto completion list when some delete all characters after . or ->: When I enter a variable name, then press . or -> to search for a certain member, I frequently have to delete all the characters I type after the . or ->, but this makes Vim hide the auto completion list. I would like to keep it visible unless I press Esc.
4. Showing related auto completion: When I type a variable and press ^X ^O, it usually shows me all the tags in the ctags file. I would like to have it showing only the tags related to the variable.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**: Some people are voting for this question, but no body seems to know the answer. So just wanted to mention that you don't have to provide a complete answer; partial answers to any of the mentioned points would be good also.

Comment: Upvotes on the question generally mean that they find the question useful, clear, concise, or interesting.  If you're getting many upvotes, it's probably because a lot of people want to know the answer and don't know themselves or want to hear more detail.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, no one seems to know the answer :-( Probably we should talk to Vim developers (or may he is only one) to consider this seriously, because this is the main disadvantage of Vim.

Answer (score 21):

[AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) is what you need.

Comment: For Python it's not perfect, but better than the default. :) +1

Answer (score 15):

For (1) when working with C++ or C [`clang complete`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) is a really nice option

Answer (score 8):

To make vim trigger a certain behavior when a key is pressed you need to map the key to a function.

For instance to map the key `.` to call some type of completion when in `INSERT` mode you would need to do:

```
:inoremap <expr> <buffer> . MyFunction()
```

and then the function would need to evaluate the context where it was called and present an appropriate answer to the user.

**Edit**: This is the basis of how `clang complete` mentioned by @honk works.

I'm not sure if you can customize the behavior of omnifunc to meet your needs but on my experience, I never went too far. As @Mikhail said, you would need to keep track of things which in practice means interpreting or even running the code to some extent.

Answer (score 5):

I use vim every day, and I'm not aware of any existing script that may do this. This action would require understanding of classes and keeping track of variables. `someObject->` means that VIM would know what class the variable `someObject` is, and then be able to search methods/variables within that class.

Writing scripts for vim is relatively easy, though like you've commented - no one has answered this yet. Up vote from me.

Comment: OK, let's simplify it then. Would it be possible to check when '.' or '->' are written and accordingly show auto completion?

Answer (score 2):

I would love to have that same functionality that you are looking for and just came across a promising plugin:

https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache looks like it could be the new autocomplpop, and seems to work quite well during my initial trials... now to configure the omni completion to work with scala~

Comment: Looks interesting. The thing, however, with Vim auto-completion is that it doesn't consider the context. For example, if I write '.' or '->' after a variable, I should only see the members of that variable, rather than all possible completions.

Comment: This is the reason why I ended using plugins like VsVim and ViEmu.

Comment: oh? I was under the impression that is what omni completion does.. but I've just started my quest to get this kind of functionality going.. I was hoping that somehow ctags and omnicompletion together could do it. I've tried switching to a more mainstream IDE, but I felt so dirty when I load it up and throws all that project overhead my way, haha... it may just come to that though~

Comment: Well, I am the opposite actually, I am under the impression that it doesn't do that, but not sure really :-) But honestly, I doubt that plugins on Vim will ever be able to offer auto completion like Visual Studio, especially if it is powered by plugins like Visual Assist or Resharper, so I believe that it is better to have a Vim plugin on Visual Studio than to have an auto completion plugin on Vim.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently discovered [YouCompleteMe](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/), it behaves similarly to the Visual Studio autocomplete tool. A demonstration can be seen here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuMyHAHF0xs

Answer (score 1):

In any case, I recommend [YouCompleteMe (YCM)](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). It provides (fuzzy) matching of identifiers of your current file, as well as path-completion, integration with external completion engines,...

ad 1)
If you like the semantic completion of eclipse, use [eclim](http://eclim.org) to integrate vim with eclipse. (alernatively use another semantic engine for YCM)

ad 2)
These 2 play nicely together btw.,: YCM can even provide the function definition (= parameter list) of the recently completed function!

ad 3)
that's what YCM does anyways

ad 4)
not quite sure, what you mean by that one. never used ctags!

P.S.: I strongly recommend using [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and [Tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) (and if you like [UndoTree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree)) additionally, what makes vim a perfect IDE for me.