# How to enable intellisense in VIM (gvim)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, vim

Is there any way I can have intellisense enabled in VIM (gvim). 
I wish to use it for STL.

Comment: Mahatma, you may find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583394/vim-making-auto-completion-smarter

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Forgive me for correcting you first, but IntelliSense is the name of the advanced code completion in Microsoft Visual Studio, not the general term for code completion.

To answer your question, you will probably want to use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). The setup is not terribly hard with vim plugin managers, but don't forget to run the shell script that compiles the compiled component of YCM. Read the docs thoroughly, most initial problems are avoidable.

Comment: ás The document says some files need to be copied to $HOME/.vim/  OR ~/.vim/. What is this location? Is it /usr/share/vim/vim72 ? P.S sorry, I'm pretty new to linux.

Comment: @Mahatma, $HOME (or ~) is where your user home directory resides. Usually, it's in `/home/username` (replace "username" with your actual username).

Comment: I have the feeling that @Mahatma is using Windows, don't you Mahatma?

Comment: @Mahatma, I extended my answer. I don't use vim on windows, so I'm not really sure about the exact location, but `:vimruntime` should show it with the full path. Something like vimfiles\plugins.

Comment: [Your first statement is wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion#VIM)

Comment: @Zoe No, Intellisense is/was a trademark of Microsoft. It was a term they coined for auto-completion in their products, but many people started to use it generally. The wikipedia page you linked points to a really old website that contains a bundle of plugins (likely added to the wiki page by the authors as an advertisement). Here is the [Microsoft trademark](https://trademarks.justia.com/744/22/intellisense-74422731.html)

Answer (score 9):

[coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) seems quite promising, integrates intellisense with vim (8.0 and above) and neovim

Comment: I used YouCompleteMe for years, until I discovered coc, it is so good !!!

Answer (score 4):

setting up ctags databases for use with omnicppcomplete

create tags for stdlibc++ and STL

```
$ ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp /usr/include/c++/4.2.4/

$ ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/boost /usr/include/boost/

$ apt-file list libc6-dev | grep -o '/usr/include/.*h'> ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist
$ ctags --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -I__wur -I__THROW -I__nonnull+ -f ~/.vim/tags/libc6 -L ~/.vim/tags/libc6-filelist
```

Here are three links you should find useful:

[Vim Intellisense](http://insenvim.sourceforge.net/)

[C++ code completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C%2B%2B_code_completion)

[OmniCppComplete : C/C++ omni-completion with ctags database](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520)