# Code completion plugin for c programming in Vim

Tags: c, vim, plugins, code-completion

I'm looking for a good code completion plugin for C programming in Vim. I already found some myself:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1764 
Even though this does have some very nice features, it only has a short gif file as documentation which makes it fairly useless to me. A shame really, I think it does almost what I want.

Ideally I want a plugin that knows the full C standard library, and has the features of the above plugin.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't remember the details (it's been a while since I last used C, and I don't have a suitable environment at hand to confirm it), but I think I did this with a combination the out-of-the-box omni-completion and ctags. Opening vim and typing `:help ft-c-omni` should get you started.

Comment: Oh, and add some key remapping as well. I know of no one that likes the default `<C-X><C-O>`.

Answer (score 5):

I would always suggest using [`clang complete`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583394/vim-making-auto-completion-smarter). The other answers there might be useful for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a long Article on the configuration, see if it helps you:

[The autocompletion C/C + + in vim](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2367-the-autocompletion-c-c-in-vim#configuration)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest the [youcompleteme](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/youcompleteme) vim plugin.

https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#installation